# ASP MVC 4 Execute custom logic when application first starts only if model has changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not sure how to formulate precisely my question. I have a requirement when any of my business models have changed ( for example: new property is added ) and the application is deployed, on start up of the application some custom logic to be triggered. For example:

this is my business model:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool hasMiddleName { get; set; }
}
```

I am adding a new property `MiddleName` and deploy the application. When the application is started again it should check if the model is changed and only then to perform some custom logic ( set `hasMiddleName` to true for example). I am not very experienced with asp mvc and I am not sure if this can be done automatically.

I am using ASP MVC 4 with .Net 4.0 and EntityFramework 4.0(I am not using ef migrations). Also, I am using sql project to manipulate the database. As I mentioned, I am not very experienced, so any ideas and explanations will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: it seems that the event you are trying to capture coincides with you deploying new bits (code) into your environment.  Can you run a script post-deployment instead of relying on code within the application to "run-once" on launch?

Comment: I haven't thought of that. I will wait for some more ideas but meanwhile please add your suggestion to a separate post, so I can accept it, if nothing better appears. Thanks!

Comment: What you want to do is part of the deployment (update data in the db or anything else). If running code is easier for your needs than writing an script, you can add a "deployment specific class". You can invoke a method on this class to apply the changes the first time the application starts (application start event in `global.asax`) and then set a flag so that the class knows that it has already been run. For example, the flag could be a version number stored in an specific field of an specific table in your db. Your class can check the version number and run accordingly